# Can't stop running using Logitech F510 playing Assassin's Creed 3

Tags: controllers, assassins-creed-3

I'm playing Assassin's Creed 3 with my Logitech Rumble Gamepad F510.
When I start running (hitting RT) I can't stop. This makes it impossible to continue playing, because I can't complete missions where I would have to aim (because aiming is not possible while running).
Is there something I could do to solve this problem.
I played the predecessors successfully with that game pad and I'm using XInput mode.

Comment: Perhaps the controller needs to be recalibrated?

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: Assuming Win7, go to the start menu and start typing `game controllers` and choose `Set up USB game controllers`. Choose your controller and go to the properties. The `Settings` tab will allow you to calibrate it again. That should hopefully reset the trigger axes.

Comment: I can see that my RT button is behaving very strange. When I start calibration it shows `**__` position. When I press the button slightly it goes up to `***_` and when I press more down to `____`. When I release the button it shows `*___` position and I think that could cause my problem because it would mean the button stays pressed. Calibration didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a hardware problem not a software one so calibration in Windows is not going to help.

The button is most probably going bad. You should be able to fix it by opening up the controller and cleaning with a brush behind the RT button. The only problem with opening the controller though is that the assembly is delicate and there is a chance you might pull a small wire and the entire controller will stop working.

There are tutorials and video available online on opening the controller properly. Do either that, or buy a new controller.

Comment: In reply to the answer: It's not a hardware problem, it's a game problem. I have tried several controllers (Xbox 360, F710, PS 3 emulator) and Conner still runs when you set him in motion. The most controllable controller is the Xbox, and the wildest one is PS 3. but it doesn't make a difference. If you use a controller, Conner will run until he decides to stop. M/KB works much better.